# Locking down SOLR on ColdFusion 9

Tags: security, solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This might belong on serverfault, so please move if it does.

We just discovered that you can get to a list of SOLR indexes by going to: `http://example.com:8983/solr/` this then allows you access to the SOLR admin for each index.  This strikes us as... a bad thing. Luckily though, this is locked down to only be accessbile from a certain IP (our office IP via the firewall), but still means the janitor can get access to our SOLR collections. not ideal.

One way to circumvent it has been to remove the admin folder, however this still allows people access to `http://example.com:8983/solr/` which isn't ideal.

I've read through the SOLR [documentation on security](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity), but can't seem to fully lock down access to `/solr/*`. It might be very well a case of looking at the wrong part of the documentation.

Using the code from the documentation:

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/core1/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>core1-role</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

and replacing `<url-pattern>/core1/*</url-pattern>` with an actual solr collection name does mean that when visiting `http://example.com:8983/solr/collection_name/` it will ask me for a login and password, however, when just trying to lock down `/solr/*` or even `*` I get no such luck.

I'm using the built in solr that came with CF9

Answer (score 1):

Is this a remote Solr server or is it on the same server as CF9, if on the same server as CF9 then you can just tell Solr to listen on 127.0.0.1. There was a patch for this for CF 9.0.0 back in 2010: http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb10-04.html

If it is a remote solr server, then you can use your network firewall, or a local firewall (windows firewall or iptables) to limit access to this port (and possibly this server) to only the CF server.

Comment: @Jarede - if you follow the link that Pete supplied it has another reference that explains how to [Limit access to the Solr collections](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-9-limit-access-solr.html).

Comment: Cheers both, i'll have a look at that, now i have to work out which patches we have installed on our CF box.